# Override Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter attribute

Tags: json.net, nswag

We are using nSwag and it generates a

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
```

attribute on a property, specifically

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))

Is there anyway to override the attribute at run, to use a different JsonConverter.  I've tried adding it to settings.Converters but that does not seem to work.

Comment: You can use the custom contract resolver from [Anyway to get JsonConvert.SerializeObject to ignore the JsonConverter attribute on a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45644338/3744182) to ignore the applied converter on the property, then add your converter in settings.  You may also need to combine that converter with the answer from [C# JsonConvert using the default converter instead of the custom converter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53401189/3744182) in case an unwanted converter was applied to the type as well as the property.